# Movie with a bomb triggered by a musical phrase played by an orchestra

Tags: identify-this-movie, action, spy-movie

I've been trying to recall the title-described movie for days now, and I can't quite place it.  It's action/thriller, as I recall, I think with either some mistaken-identity regarding the main character, or a situation where the bad guy(s) framed him. Either way, I'm pretty sure he and his reluctant partner had to work against the system to save the day.

The bomb was either under the conductor's podium, inside an organ console, or under the piano, can't remember which.

I was thinking that Martin Lawrence was the lead, but none of his titles on IMDB ring a bell.

Comment: Are there any other details to go by? Any additional plot-details or any scene descriptions you remember? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? Seeing how you mention Martin Lawrence, was this more of a comedy or a more serious movie? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question to flesh it out a little more.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Should I go ahead and add the sorts of things you suggest, even though Chenmunka already provided the answer? (I'm unfamiliar with this aspect of Movies.SE's site culture -- mainly, should I add these additional details to aid future searchers / readers of the question?)

Comment: Meh, you don't need to retrofit details from the found movie that you didn't remember into the question either, that'd be strange. Nevermind, I guess the train for improving the question is gone anyway, since it's already reliably answered. Just remember to add anything possible, including any possible meta information, for your next possible ID question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [Get Smart](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425061/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

The 2008 film version of the 1970's spy spoof television series.
Maxwell Smart has to prevent an planned explosion that will be triggered by a series of notes at a concert.  The bomb in the piano will kill the US President.

The mistaken identity and framing that you remember are similar to the plot of Get Smart.  The hero is not Martin Lawrence but Steve Carrell.

Comment: Should note that this is probably a reference to a frequently-used Looney Toons gag, wherein the bad guy has rigged up explosives to a certain key on a piano, and the hero repeatedly tries playing a song but always gets that note wrong, frustrating the villain until they push the hero aside to play it properly, forgetting about the bomb and blowing themselves up.

Answer (score 10):

This could also be [Eagle Eye](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1059786/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_17) (2008)

Its starring Shia LaBouf and the plot is very similar to the one you describe, with a bomb being planted in a necklace, set to explode on a certain note of the song played by a trumpet.

> The president arrives. Sam's class, whose recital has been moved from the Kennedy Center to the capitol to play the national anthem prior to the president's speech, begins to play. The trigger that will set off the explosive necklace is set to activate when Sam plays a sustained "high F" on his trumpet corresponding to the word "free" in the last stanza of the national anthem

Comment: Sorry - just saw you confirmed Get Smart

Comment: No worries -- this answer may be valuable for someone else.